# Div animates only on index page

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm currently in the development stages of a website and I have a div located in my header.php that contains an image of a logo. Which fades in once the user scrolls past 1000px on the website.

However when you navigate to a secondary page, the same piece of code applies because I'm using the `get_header()` code. What I am trying to achieve is to have the fadeIn animation be applied only to the index page and no other pages.

JS Code -

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (y > 1000) {
        $('.header-logo').fadeIn().addClass('is-visible');

    } else {
        $('.header-logo').fadeOut();
    }

});
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Take your javascript out of your header and place it in your index.html page.

Comment: The logo is in a fixed position across the whole website. Thats why I placed it in the header.php file. Instead of creating two identical div boxes, 1 that can be animated on the index.php and 1 that is fixed and visible to the viewer on every other page, I was seeing if there was a way to control just the one single div box?
Hope that makes sense @Tony

Answer (score 0):

you can set some kind of variable in index page and perform the required checking of that variable and perform that fadeIn animation only on the index page.

```
$(document).scroll(function () {

    if(pageNameVariable == "index")
{
    //arrange your piece of code here
}

});
```

Set that pageNameVariable only in index page. and you can keep your scrolling code anywhere .